# How to import data to CSV getting from facebook API and export the CSV file using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below Simple code that make user authentication via Facebook API and read the default user information.

This is the code snippet I have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as JSON;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isLoggedIn = false;
  Map userProfile;
  final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();

  _loginWithFB() async {
    final result = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);

    switch (result.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        final token = result.accessToken.token;
        final graphResponse = await http.get(Uri.parse(
            'https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me?fields=id,name,picture,email,name_format,birthday,hometown&access_token=${token}'));

        final profile = JSON.jsonDecode(graphResponse.body);
        print(profile);
        setState(() {
          userProfile = profile;
          _isLoggedIn = true;
        });
        break;

      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        setState(() => _isLoggedIn = false);
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        setState(() => _isLoggedIn = false);
        break;
    }
  }

  _logout() {
    facebookLogin.logOut();
    setState(() {
      _isLoggedIn = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: _isLoggedIn
                ? Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.network(
                  userProfile["picture"]["data"]["url"],
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                ),
                Text(userProfile["id"]),
                Text(userProfile["name"]),
                Text(userProfile["email"]),
                Text(userProfile["name_format"]),
                Text(userProfile["birthday"] ?? 'Birthday: empty'),
                Text(userProfile["hometown"] ?? 'Hometown: empty'),
                OutlinedButton(
                  child: Text("Logout"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _logout();
                  },
                )
              ],
            )
                : Center(
              child: OutlinedButton(
                child: Text("Login with Facebook"),
                onPressed: () {
                  _loginWithFB();
                },
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

as I need to export a CSV file to be something like the below image:
[image]

Comment: CSV is nothing more than strings followed by a comma or empty space and then a break /n that's how you have your columns and rows. You can map your list to achieve that and then a string to achieve it. Once you have your string, create a file with the xls or similar extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [CSV Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/csv).

### Step 1: add CSV plugin in the pubspec.yaml file

```
csv: ^5.0.0
```

### Step 2: create CsvController.dart file and add the following code for CsvController

```
class CsvController {

  static Future<File> getCsvFromList(List<List<dynamic>> csvDataList) async {
    try {
      String csvDataString = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(csvDataList);
      File csvFile = await _saveFile(csvDataString);
      return csvFile;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  static Future<File> getCsvFromString(String csvString) async {
    try {
      File csvFile = await _saveFile(csvString);
      return csvFile;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  static Future<String> _getFilePath(String fileName) async {
    Directory appDocumentsDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory(); // 1
    String appDocumentsPath = appDocumentsDirectory.path; // 2
    String filePath = '$appDocumentsPath/$fileName.csv'; // 3
    return filePath;
  }

  static Future<File> _saveFile(String fileDataString, {index = 0}) async {
    try {
      File file = File(await _getFilePath(
          "${General.getDate().millisecondsSinceEpoch}" +
              (index > 0 ? "($index)" : "")));
      if (!file.existsSync()) {
        // 1
        file.writeAsStringSync(fileDataString); // 2
        return file;
      } else {
        return _saveFile(fileDataString, index: index + 1);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

### Step 3: just call the respective function according to your data like below:

```
//if you have comma separated string already 
File csvFile = await CsvController.getCsvFromString(your_comma_separated_String);
if(csvFile != null){
    print("File created here :"+csvFile.path);
}else{
    print("file not created");
}

//if you have data in List<List<dynamic>> format or you can convert to this format

//for Example, To create a csv file like this
     // 1,2,3
     // "A","B","C"
     // 7,8,9

//in Your case 
List<List<dynamic>> csvData= [
["ID","username","email"],
[123,"user 1","user1@email.com"]
]

// create a list and just send it like below:
List<List<dynamic>> csvData=[
[1,2,3],
["A","B","C"],
[7,8,9]
];

File csvFile = await CsvController.getCsvFromList(csvData);
if(csvFile != null){
    print("File created here :"+csvFile.path);
}else{
    print("file not created");
}
```

**NOTE**: This class also takes care of the file that exists then it will just add the number to its name and will create it like file downloading in the browser.

For example,

File.csv exists then it will create File(1).csv

Comment: thanks a lot for you support :), bu how about the `General` key word what is related for, how can I define it?

Comment: I have found this syntax error `Undefined name 'General'.`

Comment: for the step 3 it's not clear enough for me could you explain it more, because while I am defining the `csvFile` as `File csvFile = CsvController.getCsvFromList(csvData);`  it says that `A value of type 'Future<File>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File`, I appreciate your support a lot :), I am still stuck :(

Comment: Sorry, about that. It is my utility class. You can consider General.getDate() to DateTime.now(). and It should work. Regarding File csvFile line just add await as in answer. I just updated it in answer. Thanks.

Comment: I accepted your answer but I still stuck :(, could you please help me in the belw link I have asked another question :), 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66888497/how-to-export-data-getting-from-facebook-to-csv-file-using-flutter

Comment: I will update the answer there in 10 mins